# GoogleSheet: Query with array for WHERE clause

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have this formula that works fine:

```
query('SG_69.00 USD Reward'!$A$1:$AM,"
select 
A,' ',D,W,O,P,Q,R,S,T,V,'  ','   ',AK 
where 
AM ='US'
label ' ''', '  ''', '   '''
",0)
```

However in that instance I only have one condition for the where clause.

I have use for doing a long series of OR conditions as in `AM='US' OR AM='NZ'`and so on. All comparing to the AM column.

I could do it with a long series of OR conditions as I mentioned above. But what I would like to have where `AM='named range'` (or just a range) of the various  or a solution to that effect.

Thanks.

Edit
I tried Max' solution below. However I didn't think to add what complicates my situation further. As I'm creating an array with several query functions combined like this:

```
={query('SG_39.00 USD Reward'!$A$1:$AM,"
select
A,' ',D,W,O,P,Q,R,S,T,V,'  ','   ',AK 
where 
AM = '" & join("' or AM = '", ASIA) & "'
label ' ''', '  ''', '   '''
",0);query('SG_69.00 USD Reward'!$A$1:$AM,"
select
A,' ',D,W,O,P,Q,R,S,T,V,'  ','   ',AK 
where 
AM = '" & join("' or AM = '", ASIA) & "'
label ' ''', '  ''', '   '''
",0);query('SG_179.00 USD Reward'!$A$1:$AM,"
select
A,' ',D,W,O,P,Q,R,S,T,V,'  ','   ',AK 
where 
AM = '" & join("' or AM = '", ASIA) & "'
label ' ''', '  ''', '   '''
",0);query('SG_1_000.00 USD Reward'!$A$1:$AM,"
select
A,' ',D,W,O,P,Q,R,S,T,V,'  ','   ',AK 
where 
AM = '" & join("' or AM = '", ASIA) & "'
label ' ''', '  ''', '   '''
",0);query('SG_Celery - Fulfillment.csv'!$A$1:$AV,"
select 
B,' ',S,V,Y,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,'  ','   ',AT 
where 
AV ='US'
label ' ''', '  ''', '   '''
",0)}
```

I get a value error when I try to call that.

Apparently combining it in this way doesn't work. I didn't think that that was what was causing the error. Can you think of a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may make the or conditions with help of `join` function:

`=join("' or AM = '", named_range)`

Here is sample query text formula:

`="select A, B where A = '"&join("' or A = '",D1:D4) & "'"`

[image]

**Note**

The formula has manually entered `where A = '` before `join` and closing quote `& "'"` after.

Comment: @jacob-engelbrecht, does this answer suit you? Please mark it as a correct, tick the green check.

Comment: Hi Max, I have updated my question with some more details. And thanks for you initial answer!

Comment: @jacob-engelbrecht, I've tested my solution with simple case, so it should work on a bigger formula. You may try to split your formula into small parts and see the error.

Comment: Thanks! You really saved me :)